# UIBarbutton Item - image selected and un, not shown when called programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbar, uibarbuttonitem

It works in selected state, hence when you select either one of the tabs, but when app launched the images are not visible. (I think there seems to be a problem with the unselected state and not the selected state, because that's the one not shown or called). Anyways' here is a screenshot for demonstration[image] purposes.

Here's the code use

```
header file. a simple IBOutlet uibarbutton item *Namedsomething;
[TabBarGroceryAdsIcon setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Namedsomethingselected.png"]   withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NamedsomethingUnselected.png"]];
```

I'm developing for ios 6 and using storyboard. 
Any help would be appreciated very much :)
CHeers,
Daniel Ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmaticaly, you can set our tabbarbuttons with an array.

First, set your buttons with :

```
UITabBarItem *myButton1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] tag:i]
```

Then, init a NSArray with this buttons :

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myButton1,myButton2,..., nil]
```

Finally, set your tabBar items :

```
[myTabBar setItems:myArray];
```